# Nuxt page transition js not running

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm pretty sure there is a logical reason why this is happening and i'm trying to find a way to avoid it, i'm using a page transition with gsap, what happens as the title says when the browser redirects to another page with transition, the bootstrap-select.js does not run and results to some components being blank.

```
  pageTransition: {
    name: 'page',
    mode: 'out-in',
    css: false,

    beforeEnter (el) {
      this.$gsap.set(el, {
        opacity: 0
      })
    },

    enter (el, done) {
      this.$gsap.to(el, {
        opacity: 1,
        duration: 0.5,
        ease: 'power2.inOut',
        onComplete: done
      })
    },

    leave (el, done) {
      this.$gsap.to(el, {
        opacity: 0,
        duration: 0.5,
        ease: 'power2.inOut',
        onComplete: done
      })
    }
  },
```

How can i avoid this problem and maybe run the script again on page transition?

*Edit

```
  head: {
    title: 'test',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,400i,700' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400i,700' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css' },
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.1/css/swiper.min.css' }
    ],
    script: [
      {
        type: 'text/javascript',
        src: '/js/svgSprite.js',
        body: true
      },
      {
        type: 'text/javascript',
        src: '/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js'
      },
      {
        type: 'text/javascript',
        src: '/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
        body: true
      },
      {
        type: 'text/javascript',
        src: '/vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
        body: true
      },
      {
        type: 'text/javascript',
        src: '/vendor/smooth-scroll/smooth-scroll.polyfills.min.js',
        body: true
      },
      {
        type: 'text/javascript',
        src: '/vendor/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.min.js',
        body: true
      },
      {
        type: 'text/javascript',
        src: '/vendor/object-fit-images/ofi.min.js',
        body: true
      },
      {
        type: 'text/javascript',
        src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.1/js/swiper.min.js',
        body: true
      },
      {
        type: 'text/javascript',
        src: '/js/theme.js',
        body: true
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: What is `bootstrap-select.js`? Is GSAP properly installed and are you going **to** the page where `pageTransition` is located?

Comment: bootstrap-select is a script which is declared at the end of the body, gsap is properly installed because the transition works, pageTransition is located in nuxt config.

Comment: maybe you can program your own `<nuxt/>` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65714096/10519069)

Comment: What is your script doing? What is the event listener tied to it?